# How to detect circle gesture direction?

Tags: javascript, leap-motion

THis is my code gist.

```
Leap.loop({enableGestures: true}, function(frame) {
var gestures = frame.gestures;

for (var i = 0; i < gestures.length; i++) { 
  // I want to do something when draw circle with one pointable 
   if (gesture.type == "circle" && gesture.state == "stop" && gesture.pointableIds.length == 1) {
    var isClockWise = ? ;//  how to know the direction of circle ?
  }
}
} );
```

How to know circle is clockwise or counter clock wise with gesture object ?

I was using leap motion only 2 days and really need your help.

Comment: I am getting unexpected token . when I use Leap.Loop()? Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking on the C++ sample given on the leap website, piece of code is given to detect is the circle is clockwise.

C++ code :

```
if (circle.pointable().direction().angleTo(circle.normal()) <= PI/4)
   {
      clockwiseness = "clockwise";
   }
   else
   {
      clockwiseness = "counterclockwise";
   }
```

I haven't used the Javascript API, but I think this can be something equivalent
This code hasn't been tested, but in Javascript it may be something like :

```
// considere your gesture is a circle, and there is at least one pointable object.
if (gesture.type == "circle" && gesture.state == "stop" && gesture.pointableIds.length >= 1)
{
  var dir = frame.pointables[gesture.pointableIds[0] ].direction; // get direction of the Pointable used for the circle gesture
  var angle = dir.AngleTo (circle.normal);
  var isClockWise =  angle <= (3.14 / 4);
}
```

Got all infos from Leap JS API from [GitHub](http://leapmotion.github.io/leapjs/) and [Leap Motion Developers site](https://developer.leapmotion.com/documentation/Languages/JavaScript/API/index.html)

-> Be careful `frame.pointables` return pointables objects given in arbitrary order.(Cf JS API doc). This piece of code is just for the explanation of the algorithm

Comment: actually, angleTo() function has been deprecated in new version of leapjs library. 
https://developer.leapmotion.com/forums/forums/10/topics/leap-js-how-to-detect-clockwise-and-counterclockwise-circle-gestures 
this is equal function instead.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for the tip, another AngleTo Method is in the doc of `Vector` class in the LeapJS on github (http://leapmotion.github.io/leapjs/).

Answer (score 4):

```
Leap.loop({enableGestures: true},function(frame) {
var gestures = frame.gestures,
    circle,
    pointable,
    direction,
    normal;
// Check if is there any gesture going on
if(gestures.length > 0) {
    // In this example we will focus only on the first gesture, for the sake of simplicity
    if(gestures[0].type == 'circle') {
        circle = gestures[0];
        // Get Pointable object
        circle.pointable = frame.pointable(circle.pointableIds[0]);
        // Reset circle gesture variables as nedded, not really necessary in this case
        if(circle.state == 'start') {
            clockwise = true;
        } else if (circle.state == 'update') {
            direction = circle.pointable.direction;
            // Check if pointable exists
            if(direction) {
                normal = circle.normal;
                // Check if product of vectors is going forwards or backwards
                // Since Leap uses a right hand rule system
                // forward is into the screen, while backwards is out of it
                clockwise = Leap.vec3.dot(direction, normal) > 0;
                if(clockwise) {
                    //Do clockwose stuff
                } else {
                    //Do counterclockwise stuff
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

});

Comment: This is more efficient than the accepted answer (angleTo typically needs to compute the dot product along the way).

Answer (score 1):

This is the easiest way to find out

```
var isClockwise = (circleGesture.normal[2] <= 0);
```

It will return true or false

Answer (score 0):

Tried other answers on this page and couldn't get it to work, simplified the code a bit and finally got it working. The pointableID logs normal as negative/positive based on direction of the circle gesture.

```
function pageScrollDown() {
   window.scrollBy(0,10);
};
function pageScrollUp(){
   window.scrollBy(0,-15);
};

$(window).bind('circle', function(e, gesture){

var circle = gesture;

circle.pointable = circle.pointableIds[0];
direction = gesture.normal[1];

    if(direction < 0 ) {
      pageScrollDown();
      } else {
        pageScrollUp();
}
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I have been using the "Leap Cursor library" for my project and it is really cool. Identifying a circle gesture on a element is very simple with this library.

```
var circleTrackElements = document.querySelectorAll(".myDOMElements");
for (var i = 0; i < allTiles.length; i++) {
    circleTrackElements[i].addEventListener("leap-circle-stop", function(e) {
        console.log("CIRCLE DETECTED");
    });
};
LeapManager.init({
    maxCursors : 1,
    interactiveSelector : ".myDOMElements"
});
```

[GITHUB link for the library](https://github.com/aphex/leap-cursor-library.js)

Comment: -1 since it doesn't address the actual question, which was about the direction of the circle being drawn.